# Where is the list of scripts to be loaded stored?

Tags: templates, joomla3.0, script-tag

In a template, there are parts that call Joomla functions to load several javascript files, and others to load css files. The js files aren't hard-coded in the template files, AFAIK.
Where does Joomla store this list of paths for Javascript files?

---

**Edit**

---

I'm looking for the source of the list used like this in the template:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$this->language = $doc->language;

$load_favthb = true;
$lscripts = $doc->_scripts;

foreach ($lscripts as $k => $v) {
  if (strpos($k, 'favth-bootstrap') !== false) { $load_favthb = false; break; }
}
```

Where is the source for `$doc->_scripts` stored?

Comment: It would be most helpful if all Joomla questions were posted on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  When support is shared across the myriad of channels, platforms, and social networks, future researchers have a harder/slower time finding the knowledge that they require.  Please help me to grow JSE, Sloan.

Comment: Thanks @mickmackusa. Will do in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to javascript files loaded by your template (as opposed to say an extension on your site), then the paths to these files are typically in one of your template's files.

There are all sorts of ways of building a Joomla template, and so these paths aren't specified in the same place in every template. But you'd always start by looking near the top of `/templates/template-in-question/index.php`

As an example, you probably have the Beez3 template installed on your Joomla 3 site.

Start by opening /templates/beez3/index.php, and if you work your way down from the top you'll find the Javascript files are loaded at lines 80-83
[image: javascript files loaded]

Instead of loading javascript files in index.php, some templates include them in a secondary file (often named 'params' or 'head' or 'includes') which is inserted into index.php.

Either way, start by scanning down from the top of your template's index.php file

**Edit**

> Where is the source for $doc->_scripts stored?

Google `<jdoc: include type=”head” />`  if you want to know all the details, but most come from `site-root/media/jui/`  and `site-root/media/system/`

If you were to edit one of these files directly, there's the chance that your edit could be overwritten with a Joomla update.

A safer way would be to remove the js script you don't want, and then add a replacement.

```
// remove unwanted script . Path is relative to site root
unset($doc->_scripts[$this->baseurl.'/path/to/unwanted-script']);  
  
// add your replacement script. Path is relative to template root
$doc->addScript($tpath.'/js/new-script');
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. And I had found those bits of code. I've updated the question with a code sample from the template, and some clarification of the question. Basically, there is a script being loaded for field validation that I want to replace.

Comment: Thanks for the update and example! That works great!

Comment: Excellent, I'm pleased this helped. Thanks for letting me know!